# I get a warning loading magit sometimes

Tags: magit

```
In magit-repolist-mode:
magit-repos.el:151:9:Warning: assignment to free variable ‘x-stretch-cursor’

In magit-submodule-list-mode:
magit-submodule.el:332:9:Warning: assignment to free variable
‘x-stretch-cursor’
```

Any way I can stop that?

Comment: Do you build Emacs without graphics?

Comment: I use emacs in the terminal and so I install emacs-nox. So, it is built without X.

Comment: I think it's a bug in magit, `x-stretch-cursor` is only defined when Emacs is built with graphics, but magit assigns to that variable unconditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/04e7e017aa718ac9e1cd9bc5c3d71d919a82f9f2), on the `master` branch. The first release to contain that commit will be `v2.10.2`.